# 'gh' is not recognized... error while trying to create GitHub repo from command prompt

Tags: git, github, github-cli

I'm following the instructions on how to add an existing project to GitHub from [GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line). However, I get an `'gh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` error message when I try to use `gh repo create fs1` command in the project root directory as instructed. Here `fs1` is my project name. I browsed StackOverflow but couldn't find any help yet. What am I missing?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The page you are following doesn't include the instructions to install the GitHub CLI, so it is likely you don't have it installed (it doesn't come with git as far as I know).

Installation instructions can be found here: https://cli.github.com/

Comment: Now the repository got created but I got `error: remote origin already exists.` error whilte creating it.

Comment: That *probably* means that the repository name you're trying to create is already one you've created on GitHub, I would check there to be sure you haven't done that. I could be wrong though

Comment: I had `fs1` on GitHub earlier but I deleted it to try the creation from command prompt. Now I managed to create it from there, but I get these `already exists` -type of errors no matter what I try to do with it.

Comment: I think I got it now. I just skipped all the previous steps and continued from `git branch -M main` and then `git push -u origin main.` Now mt repo looks like this: [fs1](https://github.com/jonklouef/fs1)

Comment: Just a silly question, but perhaps others will benefit from answer, I assumed because I had installed `git`, it would enable me to use `gh` command from `Git Bash`?  However when I try and do `gh repo create my-project-name` I get `bash: gh: command not found`.  When I run `$ git version` I get `git version 2.33.1.windows.1`.  Do I have to download and install `GitHub CLI` from https://cli.github.com *as well as* have `git` installed?  And then `gh` will be available from `Git Bash`?  Update:  Yes, that seems to work, was prompted to authenticate with `gh auth login` beforehand.

Comment: Mac users can install using brew, `brew install gh`

Answer (score 12):

`gh` is github cli.
Install github cli:

### windows

```
choco install gh
```

( choco is installed with nodejs most of the time )

### mac

```
brew install gh
```

for linux: https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/install_linux.md

ref: https://cli.github.com/manual/installation

Comment: In most cases, don't forget to restart your terminal

Comment: `winget install GitHub.cli` might be a better command for windows, as winget should be installed by default now

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I didn't have gh installed.

I installed the gh, but the same error occurred.

I checked the environment variables and gh location was there.

I restarted windows, the error went away :)

Comment: Just restart the terminal is enought. In my case, I'm using node.js so I just closed the node command line and opened a new node command line window and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, with Windows 10 or 11, to avoid having to download even more crap, use:
`winget install --id github.cli`

This can be done straight from the VSCode Terminal.

Comment: Excellent use of winget for Windows 10 and above.

Comment: Great! Just make sure you restart your terminal after installing it, as some other answer below stated.